# Get date with jQuery UI month picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the [jQuery UI Month Picker Plugin](https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/) to add a month picker in my app.

I don't find the way to get the value of the selected month in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

I see in documentation you could get the month as a number! simply create a array with 12 months and use the method `GetSelectedMonth()` and use that number to get the relevant month from the array.

```
var arr = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
arr[GetSelectedMonth()-1] //-1 is used since array starts from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the link you could get the month as a number! simply create a array with 12 months and use that number to get the relevant month from the array.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/JLydp/"
```